# How to record video of your screen inside an ios app with code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Just like "ShowMe" app in apple store, users can paint and record the actions as a video.
Do you guys know how to do that in code?
Thanks!

Comment: I think dot was hinting that you should provide the answer if you found it on your own. Or accept Simon Lee's answer if that helped.

Answer (score 9):

We recently had this question and found a fantastic article which uses the layer of your view and the media framework.

[Check out link here...](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673)

We modified it to use the presentation layer instead though instead of...

```
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
```

use...

```
[[self.layer presentatationLayer] renderInContext:context];
```

... this captures animation block transitions as well. Very neat.

Comment: @RayZhang I am also building a similar application to Show Me but with more features. I am stuck with recording the screen while the user paints on the screen. The issue is with the iPad Retina. Can you share the codes if you have used to overcome the issue?

Comment: @Simon: Can you please help for the same code for performance improvement?? I am using that code to record the video but I am also recording audio and also have drag and drop functionality with UIImageView. Now when I drag the image while recording video, dragging is very much ICHY, can you please tell me how to gain performance with that?? thanks in advance...