# Capturing the screen and writing it to a file in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, uiviewanimation, avassetwriter

I got an application that play a few UIView Animations with sounds (using AVAudioPlayer).

Can someone please show how I can capture everything that is going on inside a view and save it as a video file on the device? i wasn't able to find a single AVAssetWriter's example that would work for me.

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial regarding AVAsset tracker. 
please check this link :
         http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673
Also attaching the stack overflow link about this question which is discussed before :
[How to record video of your screen inside an ios app with code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731059/how-to-record-video-of-your-screen-inside-an-ios-app-with-code)
Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick answer! but this code doesn't capture the UIView animations i add on it. you have any idea why is that?